# Okta AD group not matching with Jenkins Role

Tags: jenkins, okta

I have set up the following Okta AD group `deployer-beta` and assigned myself to this role in Okta.

[image]

And have also enabled the group to match regex `.*`
[image]

On Jenkins side, I have installed the plugin `Role-based Authorization Strategy` and configured the same name `deployer-beta` as an "Item Role" in Jenkins
[image]

I would expect when I first log in to Jenkins that I am assigned to this role; however, I am not as seen below:
[image]

What am I missing for the Okta AD role to match my Jenkins role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the role to match by setting up the role `deployer_beta_role` as an Item Role (this can also be a Global Role) under the "Manage Roles" tab in Jenkins

[image]

And then in the "Assign Roles" tab, create a group called `deployer_beta` and assign `deployer_beta_role` to that group.

[image]

Now when a user logs in via Okta SAML 2.0 and they are assigned to the `deployer_beta` Okta AD group, they will automatically log in with the `deployer_beta` privileges that were set up in Jenkins.

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. So there was a mismatch between the Okta AD group name assignment and the regex pattern being used for matching the group?

Comment: Yep correct, thank you for your answer below that helped me narrow it down @VonC

Answer (score 1):

Just experiment with different [regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), other than `(?i)deployment/beta($|/.*)`, because that should be a mismatch between the Okta AD group name assignment and the regex pattern being used for matching the group.
The Okta AD group name `deployer-beta` and the assignment `deployer-beta werkdayinternal.com/Workday/ApplicationGroups/deployer-betə` do not match the regex pattern `(?i)deployment/beta($|/.*)`.

Update the regex pattern in Okta to match the actual [group name](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) or assignment.
The updated regex might look something like `(?i)deployer-beta($|/.*)`, based on your naming convention.